# Proof, that equation decribes trace of curve, which is supposed to be simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, analysis, differential-geometry

The equation, representing the trace of the curve
$$
 \varphi(x) = (\cos^3(t), \sin^3(t))
$$
is $1 = x^{\frac{2}{3}} + y^{\frac{2}{3}}$.

> *Proof*: Let $(x,y) = (\cos^3 t, \sin^3 t)$, then $x^{1/3} = \cos t, y^{1/3} = \sin t$, and so $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = \cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t) = 1$. Therefore it fulfills the equation. The other direction, that if some $(x,y)$ fulfills the equation, then there exists some $t$ such that $x = \cos t, y = \sin t$ is simple.

I do not see that the second part is simple? If some $x,y \in \mathbb R$ such that
$$
 x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1
$$
then how to construct a $t \in \mathbb R$ such that $x = \cos(t), y = \sin(t)$. To set
$t := \cos^{-1}(x)$ I first have to show that $x \in [-1,1]$, and then it must be $y = \sin(\cos^{-1}(x))$, but how to show that? To me this seems to be quite involved, or have I overlooked something?

Comment: For $x,y\geq 0$, $\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^2+\left(y^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^2=1$, then there exists $\theta\in \Bbb R$ such that $x^{\frac{1}{3}}=\cos(\theta) $ and $y^{\frac{1}{3}}=\sin(\theta)$...that is $x=\cos^3(\theta)$ and $y=\sin^3(\theta)$ the original form!

Comment: Thank you! Can you please make this an answer, so I can mark it as accepted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x,y\geq 0$, $\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}} \right)^2+\left(y^{\frac{1}{3}} \right)^2=1$, then there exists $\theta\in \Bbb R$ such that $x^{\frac{1}{3}}=\cos(\theta)$ and $y^{\frac{1}{3}}=\sin(\theta)$, that is $x=\cos^3(\theta)$ and $y=\sin^3(\theta)$ the original form!